# AWS S3 Android : The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to run sample code for upload and download files to bucket using android and below sample
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/main/S3TransferUtilitySample
I have followed documentation and configured awsconfiguration.json like below

```
{
  "Version": "1.0",
  "IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
  },
"CredentialsProvider": {
  "CognitoIdentity": {
    "Default": {
      "PoolId": "us-east-2:42d8bef5-09f9-43bc-a452-abcddkdjkdjkd",
      "Region": "us-east-2"
    }
  }
},
  "S3TransferUtility": {
    "Default": {
      "Bucket": "myappbucket",
      "Region": "us-east-2"
    }
  }
}
```

But its getting failed with below error

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect; Request ID:
```

Let me know if anyone is success running that code. Thanks

Comment: are you sure your region is "us-east" and not "ap-south-1"

Comment: Meena Please have look [Documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/android). Go through step by step. Make sure your server should be "ap-south-1" for india.